# Existence of square root in $\mathbb Z_n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences, quadratic-residues

I had this question on my final exam and I struggled with it.

It asks to prove or disprove the following:

> $$\forall m \in Z, \ \forall \ [a] \in Z_{m}, \ \exists  \ [b] \in Z_{m}, [a]=[b]^{2} $$

I claimed that it's true, and wrote that for an arbitrary $m$, and an arbitrary $a$,  $[a] = [b]^{2}$ is equivalent to solving $x \equiv b^{2} \pmod{m}$ which is possible since $\gcd(m,1) \mid b^2$ .

Comment: The equation is more something like $a=x^2$ mod $m$, which may not have a solution. For instance $m=3$, $a=[2]$ then $[0]^2=[0]$, $[1]^2=[1]$ and $[2]^2=[1]$ so $[x]^2=0$ or $1$ modulo $3$ and hence never $2$ modulo $3$.

Comment: Hmm. Try working out a few examples with small values of m, say 3,4,5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No way. In $\mathbb{Z}_3$, the equation $x^2 = \hat 2$ has no solution.

Answer (score 1):

In words, this is asking if every element of $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is a perfect square.  This is false, and can be shown by a counterexample.

Take $m=3$, and consider the congruence class $a=[2]$.  Since $[0]^2 = [0], [1]^2=[1]$, and $[2]^2 = [1]$, there is no $b\in\mathbb Z_m$ such that $a = b^2$.